# Meteor.user().profile only defined after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a helper called 'isActive' and a template named 'create'.. see below

```
Template.create.isActive = function () {
  return Meteor.user().profile.isActive;
};
```

When I try to run this code it returns the following in console: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined".

I solve this by using iron-router to wait for profile to load:

```
//startup on server side:
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
      {fields: {'profile.isActive': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

//startup on client side
Meteor.subscribe('userData');

//router
this.route('create', {
  path: 'create',
  waitOn : function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('userData');
  },
  data : function () {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
  action : function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    }
  }
});
```

BUT... it only works when I refresh the page and not on initial load. Anybody know why this is happening? And have a fix or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined" you need to check that `Meteor.user()` has returned an object.  The standard pattern is:

```
Template.create.isActive = function () {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  return user && user.profle.isActive;
};
```

Once your helper throws an error, reactivity will not work so you need to make sure to handle the case where the subscription data has not arrived yet.

Also, waiting on the 'userData' subscription will delay the template loading but the user profile is published automatically on login ( as a null subscription ).  So your wait is causing an arbitrary delay which would increase the chance that Meteor.user() will be defined but it is not directly waiting on the data you need.

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck.. first off it doesn't seem like I need iron-router, secondly when I try to implement this it solves the problem, but creates a new one... the 'Template.create.rendered = function ()' no longer gets rendered. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Does the rendered function manipulate something in the DOM?  If it is not called that is a bug that should be reported. More likely is that it gets called but is not having the desired effect.  Not sure how related that is to the problem above so maybe start another thread.